# Hazelcast L2 cache for Hibernate throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hazelcast

I have a multi-module, Spring Boot project. One module, 'entities' contains the the Hibernate configuration including the Hazelcast L2 cache configs. This is a .jar (not a Spring Boot)

Another module is 'web' which has a dependency on 'entities' but is a Boot Application.

'entities' has the following dependencies:

```
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate5</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>

    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
```

'hazelcast-hibernate5' has a managed dependency on hazelcast 3.5.5 which I exclude.

When I run the 'web' application (Spring Boot), I get the following error which originates from the 'entities' configuration file (where the L2 cache is declared). I do not use XML, this is Java config.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.DataSerializerHook

In eclipse I search by "type" & can find DataSerializerHook which is a dependency of 'entities' ... as expected.

The reason i exclude hazelcast 3.5.5 from hazelcast-hibernate5 is because in 3.5.5 DataSerializerHook is in com.hazelcast.nio.serialization. In hazelcast 3.7.1 its in com.hazelcast.internal.serialization. Initially, I was getting a classCastException b/c of this. This is now resolved.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`hazelcast-hibernate5` version 1.2 depends on Hazelcast version 3.7 as can be seen [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate5/blob/v1.2/pom.xml#L40) You should not need any exclusions in your Maven configuration to be able to use it with Hazelcast 3.7. Look for dependencies in your Maven configuration which might have transitive dependencies on a previous Hazelcast version.

You can use [Maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) or your IDE's built-in capabilities to show transitive Maven dependencies.